# How would I use the purrr package to calculate the days_since column in my_tibble

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I have a tibble (my_tibble) that has two columns day, and rained. Day is the day number and rained is an integer value equal to 1 if it rained on that day and equal to zero if it did not rain. I want to calculate a third column, days_since, that represents the number of days (excluding the current day) since it has rained. After a lot of trial and error, I came up with a script that yields the desired output (see reprex below), however, it's not very elegant, and I was curious if this could be achieved using the purrr package.

My brute force approach calculated a helper column, temp, that represented the days (number) that it rained. Then I subtracted that number from the day number to get days_since, except in the case when it rained on the current day, in that case I subtracted lead(temp) from the day to get days_since.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(reprex)

my_tibble <- tibble(day = 1:10, rained = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))


my_tibble <- my_tibble %>% 
  arrange(desc(day)) %>% 
  mutate(seed = 1L) %>% 
  mutate(rows_that_are_1 = day * rained) %>% 
  mutate(temp = if_else(row_number() == 1, NA_real_, rows_that_are_1)) %>% 
  fill(temp, .direction = c('up')) %>% 
  mutate(temp = if_else(temp ==0, NA_real_, temp)) %>% 
  fill(temp, .direction = c('up')) %>% 
  select(day, rained, temp) %>% 
  mutate(days_since = if_else(day-temp >0, day-temp, day-lead(temp))) %>% 
  replace_na(list(days_since =0)) %>% 
  select(day, rained, days_since)


print(my_tibble)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>      day rained days_since
#>    <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1    10      1          4
#>  2     9      0          3
#>  3     8      0          2
#>  4     7      0          1
#>  5     6      1          3
#>  6     5      0          2
#>  7     4      0          1
#>  8     3      1          2
#>  9     2      0          1
#> 10     1      1          0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sbtscs()` function in the `stevemisc` package will do this for you, except you'll have to modify the first day's value.  The function is meant to be used with multiple cross-sectional units over time, so you would have to make a cross-sectional identifier if you don't have one arlready.  That's what `obs` is below.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stevemisc)
my_tibble <- tibble(day = 1:10, rained = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))

my_tibble %>% 
  mutate(obs = 1) %>% 
  sbtscs(., event=rained, tvar=day, csunit = obs) %>% 
  mutate(spell = ifelse(day == 1, 0, spell + 1)) %>%
  select(-obs) %>% 
  rename(days_since = spell)
#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>      day rained days_since
#>    <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1      1          0
#>  2     2      0          1
#>  3     3      1          2
#>  4     4      0          1
#>  5     5      0          2
#>  6     6      1          3
#>  7     7      0          1
#>  8     8      0          2
#>  9     9      0          3
#> 10    10      1          4
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You can generate sequences from where `rained == 1`, but firstly need to ensure the first value of the vector is `1` and add another `1` to the end.  Then after the sequences have been generated add a `0` to the beginning and remove the last value:

```
library(dplyr)

my_tibble |>
  mutate(
    days_since = head(c(0, sequence(diff(which(c(replace(rained, 1, 1), 1) == 1)), 1)), -1)
  )

# A tibble: 10 × 3
     day rained days_since
   <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>
 1     1      1          0
 2     2      0          1
 3     3      1          2
 4     4      0          1
 5     5      0          2
 6     6      1          3
 7     7      0          1
 8     8      0          2
 9     9      0          3
10    10      1          4
```

Or a slower alternative using `accumulate()` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

my_tibble |>
  mutate(
    days_since = head(accumulate(r, ~ if(!.y) .x  + 1 else .y, .init = 0), -1)
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

in base R:

```
d <- with(my_tibble, day[rained == 1])
c(numeric(d[1]), sequence(diff(d)))
[1] 0 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 4
```

---

You could write everything in one line:

```
transform(my_tibble, days_since=c(rep(0,(a<-day[rained == 1])[1]), sequence(diff(a))))
   day rained days_since
1    1      1          0
2    2      0          1
3    3      1          2
4    4      0          1
5    5      0          2
6    6      1          3
7    7      0          1
8    8      0          2
9    9      0          3
10  10      1          4
```

---

Try with a different dataset where it did not rain in the first 3 days and you will notice some of the some of the solutions will fail. This is the notion of rep function

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. It is more verbose, but makes it clearer how we can conceptually approach this kind of problems:

```r
library(dplyr)

my_tibble |> 

  # cluster data into rleid of blocks with one day rain
  mutate(days_since = cumsum(rained)) |> 

  # days_since is just the row number per group or row number -1 (in most cases)
  mutate(days_since = row_number(), .by = days_since) |> 

  # in OPs case we need to adjust for day one and the handling of days with rain
  mutate(days_since = lag(days_since, 1, 0))

#> # A tibble: 10 × 3
#>      day rained days_since
#>    <int>  <dbl>      <int>
#>  1     1      1          0
#>  2     2      0          1
#>  3     3      1          2
#>  4     4      0          1
#>  5     5      0          2
#>  6     6      1          3
#>  7     7      0          1
#>  8     8      0          2
#>  9     9      0          3
#> 10    10      1          4
```

Data from OP

```r
my_tibble <- tibble(day = 1:10, rained = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1))
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>